# Pandas_profiling-1.4.1 throws ZeroDivisionError for valid data set ,Which pandas version is stable?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-profiling

Pandas_profiling-1.4.1 throws ZeroDivisionError for valid sample data set, which pandas version is stable?

Is it due to pandas library open issue? [ZeroDivisionError when using version 1.4.1](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/issues/94)

I tried with pandas 1.4.0 but it is running infinitely without any success/failure.

Any clue on how to resolve this issue?

Python Code:

```
    file_path = "C:/profiling/Test.csv"
try:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, parse_dates=True)
    profile = pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(df)
    desc = pandas_profiling.describe(df)
    print(desc);
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    print("Error ")
```

Sample csv data set:

```
CourseName
PHY
MATHS
MATHS
MATHS
PHY
PHY
PHY
CHEM
CHEM
CHEM
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this issue against the latest version (2.0.3), the problem is resolved.